# MongoDB .msi installer not working on Windows 10

Tags: mongodb

I have downloaded the .msi multiple times and tried to run in a variety of ways, however, I cannot install MongoDB on my windows 10 machine. When I click the .msi, I get the first "preparing to install" pop-up and then it just goes away. Nothing happens.

I tried downloading the zip folder which contains a bunch of .exes.. but still nothing. I'm not sure how to get this to work on my local.

Thoughts?

Comment: Maybe a permissions issue?  Try to run the MSI as administrator...

Comment: Does Event Viewer show any problems?

Comment: @barrypicker tried this, no dice.

Comment: @VictorWilson nope nothing at all.

Comment: You may want to try to output a log file during running of an MSI.  Hopefully this can shed some light on the problem.  This can be achieved by running the MSI in the context of the MSIEXEC program.  Example command: `msiexec /i  yourfile.msi /L*v  c:\temp\yourinstall.log`.  See https://support.symantec.com/us/en/article.howto4103.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason, the latest documentation doesn't include the manual installation process.

Download the distribution ZIP and extract it to `c:\mongodb\` or equivalent.

Then from the resultant `bin` directory you can run an administrative powershell command (be sure to replace the paths with real paths that exist on your system):

```
PS C:\mongodb\bin> ./mongod.exe --install --logpath="c:\\path\\to\\logfile.log" --dbpath="c:\\path\\to\\data\\on\\disc"
```

This will create a windows service named "MongoDB" which should start automatically.  If it doesn't, you can run `net start MongoDB` from your admin PS prompt.

Comment: i had to remove the beginning "./", but here's the result i got: 

c:\mongodb\bin>mongod.exe --install --logpath="c:\\path\\to\\logfile.log" --dbpath="c:\\path\\to\\data\\on\\disc"
2020-02-06T13:53:24.983-0800 F  CONTROL  [main] Failed global initialization: FileNotOpen: Failed to open "c:\\path\\to\\logfile.log"

Comment: You'll need to replace the data and log paths with real paths to your log file and data directory.  I've edited my answer to be more clear.

Comment: the mongod.exe process is the mongo database engine process.  Your example shows running this as the current user with elevated permissions.  I don't believe this will create a windows service.  I believe the installer is required to create the windows service registration.  If you run the mongod process this way you will need to keep the powershell session active.  This might be fine for experimentation uses but would likely not be sufficient for a production system.  This answer does not address the OPs original question - how to get the MSI to work.

Comment: @barrypicker I have used this method for 6 years.  This creates a MongoDB service (at least in every version from 2.6 to 4.0).  If you don't believe me, you're welcome to try.

Comment: @barrypicker The `--install` flag is the important one to note here.

Comment: @barrypicker I'd also argue OP's only question is: "Thoughts?"

Comment: marked as answer. running in powershell did this trick. i'm brand new to mongo, is there an advised place to put the data folder? within the mongodb folder? or... other?

Comment: @VictorWilson - Thank you for the education.  I did try this and found your solution works.  Apparently the mongod process for Windows includes additional command line options to register the binary (in its current location) as a service.  I had no idea that option existed.  Obviously these options are not included in a MacOS or Linux variant of mongod.  As pointed out in your answer this is a two step process - run the install command (does not start the mongod process, just registers it as a service) then start the process using the service controls.  Thanks again for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

Please download Mongodb from there official sites and also there is a very easy guide to install the mongodb on various OS.

Reference:- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

Comment: Please just ping me here if your issue is still exists after performing with above steps. Happy to help more if issues exists.

Comment: i just re-downloaded. still the same issue exists. when i run the .msi, a window pops up saying "preparing to install" and then immediately closes. nothing happens after that.